# scrape the overview

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wonder why I cannot scrape this company overview. An example is that I want to scrape Walmart's size, which is 10000+ employees. Below is my code, not sure why the info I am looking for is not there...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 



url = f'https://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-Walmart-EI_IE715.11,18.htm'
    # f'https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Google-Engineering-Reviews-EI_IE9079.0,6_DEPT1007_IP{pg}.htm?sort.sortType=RD&sort.ascending=false&filter.iso3Language=eng'

r = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Glassdoor site requires login. Look at the content of r variable - there`s probably nothing that looks like the site you`re seeing in the browser, because whole content would be loaded after you authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    raw_data = session.get(f'https://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-Walmart-EI_IE715.htm').text
    
    script = [s.text for s in BeautifulSoup(raw_data, "lxml").find_all("script") if "window.appCache" in s.text][0]
    json_data = json.loads(re.findall(r'(\"Employer:\d+\":)(.+)(,\"ROOT_QUERY\")', script)[0][1])

    data = {
        "id": json_data["id"],
        "shortName": json_data["shortName"],
        "website": json_data["website"],
        "type": json_data["type"],
        "revenue": json_data["revenue"],
        "headquarters": json_data["headquarters"],
        "size": json_data["size"],
        "yearFounded": json_data["yearFounded"]
    }
    
    print(data)
```

Output:

```json
{
  'id': 715,
  'shortName': 'Walmart',
  'website': 'careers.walmart.com',
  'type': 'Company - Public',
  'revenue': '$10+ billion (USD)',
  'headquarters': 'Bentonville, AR',
  'size': '10000+ Employees',
  'yearFounded': 1962
}
```

If you only need "size" then just use e.g. `size = json_data["size"]`